# Releasing a ViewController?

Tags: ios, memory-management, viewcontroller

I have a `UITabBar` application which has 5 tabs (`viewControllers`). There's a `viewController` in it which I want to release when it's not active I think it's via `viewDidUnload` but I don't exactly how. I need the code for this, please.

***EDIT: I just want to know how to normally release a `viewController` when it's not active.***

Comment: Sorry, where is this view controller referenced from?

Comment: Actually I'm beginner and I can't clearly understand your comment ... If I'm not wrong it's from PagedScrollViewController4.h, PagedScrollViewController4.m .. Sorry If the question isn't clear

Comment: To be more clearer I just want how to normally release any viewController
P.S. : My app doesn't use ARC

Comment: Well the issue is that things like tab bars keep a reference to the view controllers, so I want to know where *this* view controller is referenced from.

Comment: Give me just few minutes and I'll know and I'll tell you

Comment: @trojanfoe Now I'm using ARC .. I have referenced to it from another tab what should I do then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to release the view controller from outside of the view controller - it can't release itself ...

So e.g. when you switch to another tab, you can release the view controller of the last tab in your `UITabBar` class.

**Addition**:

Looking at your comment, releasing the view controller is the completely wrong thing to do (next to that, a `UITabBarController` is meant to keep all of its view controllers alive all the time normally).

You should implement a function to refresh the bookmarks in the view controller, and call it either when the bookmark view controller appears (the `viewWillAppear` function) or if for whatever reason necessary in the UITabBarController's delegate when the bookmark view controller is selected (delegate function `(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`).

Maybe you should [read up on the UITabBarController here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: If you don't hold a reference to that view controller....then you don't need to worry about it.....the tab bar controller will release that view controller when it's finished with it. Why do you want to release a view controller when switching tabs?

Comment: The tab which I want to release is a bookmarks tab .. I need it to be released just to show new bookmarks when it's added .. So I'll need to reopen the app to see new bookmarks .. But If it was release I won't need to do this

Comment: @TheEye Thank you for your neat answer man! but let's say this bookmarks tab is an NSMutableArray which is called "favorited" and I view this by `self.pageImages = favorited;` can you please tell me how to refresh it when it's selcted via `viewWillAppear` Thank you again :)

Comment: You should post the code of your bookmark view controller, otherwise it's not clear what you are doing.

Comment: I'll add it now give me few minutes

Comment: @TheEye For some reason my code couldn't be formatted properly .. Anyway my code is exactly like the one in this tutorial UIScrollView With Paging http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content .. But with some little changes sorry for this and thank you for your patience :)

Comment: I took a quick look - all the initialization stuff for your pageImages array that is done in the viewDidLoad function should be done in the viewWillAppear function, then it should be fine. Just take care that you do not create any visual elements in the viewWillAppear (as it will be called more often).